# How to add to user input into a new variable

Tags: python

I am struggling with my code and can't seem to figure it out.
So the user inputs how much money they have to start with. Then they enter how much they want to bet. Then the program outputs if they win, lose, push, or get a blackjack. The probabilities of getting each are shown in game function in the if statements.
What I am wanting to do is have the total they get and have it as the new total and the user continues betting from that new total until they enter 'x' to end the program. I am not sure how to do this.

```
import random
print('BLACKJACK!')
print('')
print('Blackjack payout is 3:2')
print('Enter \'x\' for bet to exit')
print('')

money = float(input('Starting money: '))
#global variables
bet_amount = 0

#play the game
def game(bet_amount):
    total = float(money)
    number = random.randint(1, 100)
    if number >= 6 and number <= 42:
        print('You won.')
        print('Money: ', total + int(bet_amount))

    elif number >= 43 and number <= 51:
        print('You pushed')
        print('Money: ', total - int(bet_amount))

    elif number >=52 and number <= 100:
        print('You lost.')
        print('Money: ', total)

    elif number >= 1 and number <= 5:
        print('You got a blackjack!')
        print('Money: ', ((int(bet_amount) * 1.5) + total))
    return total


def main():
    while True:
        print('')
        bet_amount = input('Bet amount: ')
        if bet_amount == 'x':
            print('Bye!')
            break
        else:
            game(bet_amount)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Specify what issue you are having with the code.

Comment: Show us the issues you're getting; errors, messages, etc. As someone beginning to code in Python, I suggest you try [pythontutor](http://pythontutor.com/) to get a visual workflow of how your code is working.

Comment: The code works fine, I just want whatever the result of getting either a blackjack, win, lose, or push, to be the new total and restart the game with that total as the starting amount of money and continue placing bets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should assign the calculated value of the new `total` back to `total` instead of just printing it:

```
import random
print('BLACKJACK!')
print('')
print('Blackjack payout is 3:2')
print('Enter \'x\' for bet to exit')
print('')

#play the game
def game(money, bet_amount):
    total = float(money)
    bet_amount = int(bet_amount)
    number = random.randint(1, 100)
    if number >= 6 and number <= 42:
        total += bet_amount
        print('You won.')

    elif number >= 43 and number <= 51:
        total -= bet_amount
        print('You pushed')

    elif number >=52 and number <= 100:
        print('You lost.')

    elif number >= 1 and number <= 5:
        total += bet_amount * 1.5
        print('You got a blackjack!')
    return total


def main():
    money = float(input('Starting money: '))
    while money >= 0:
        print('')
        bet_amount = input('Bet amount: ')
        if bet_amount == 'x':
            print('Bye!')
            break
        else:
            money = game(money, bet_amount)
            print('Money: ', money)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```